# Why is rpm -qa showing nothing in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, rpm

I am doing `dpkg -l` and it is listing all installed packages, but
`rpm -qa` is not showing anything.

Why is this the case? Do I have to make some changes so that rpm will also display the installed packages?

Comment: Because `rpm` and `dpkg` use different databases? As to changes, yes: Use `apt-get` and remember that this is not Fedora/CentOS/RHEL, but Ubuntu.

Comment: could you please tell me how to switch to rpm database so that I can see what is in that database?

Comment: There is nothing, which is why `rpm -qa` is showing nothing. What do you expect to see?

Comment: As muru said, it's two different systems. Are you by any chance trying to follow a guide that was written for a RHEL based Linux distribution? The Debian wiki has a nice article that helps you convert some of the common 'RPM' commands to DPKG ones. It also explains how to convert RPM files to DEB files etc.

Comment: yes correct I am doing RHEL based Linux distribution. I also went and tried .rpm file to .deb files but my main problem is i don't have rpm files. I am not getting where and what mistake am i making.

Comment: Why would you actually want to do that? What you're trying to achieve in general? Most likely you don't need to convert rpms to debs either - a lot of software is available in debs already.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comments, you say that you're "doing RHEL based Linux distribution" and that you don't know what mistake you're making.

The mistake you're making is that you are thinking that Ubuntu is a RHEL based distribution.  Ubuntu is a Debian based system, and uses `dpkg` as the package management system.  It does not use RPM packages, which is why using `rpm` will return nothing.  The use of `dpkg -l` was somewhat more accurate to use, as `dpkg` is the underlying package system.

If you want a RHEL based distribution to work with, CentOS and Fedora are possible alternative options.  (However, support for those is not on this site, which is Ubuntu only, so for Fedora and CentOS questions, try [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't use rpm packages, hence you don't see them (as some people stated already in comments). Ubuntu is using deb packages so you have to use proper tools to handle them, like: dpkg, apt and some other more or less convenient tools to handle repos in text console or graphics mode.

So - dpkg -l in that case was the proper tool.